# How to have mobile bookmarks appear on desktop chrome bookmarks bar?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

When I use my smartphone chrome browser, I store my bookmarks at the mobile bookmarks. When I manage bookmarks on the desktop browser, I can see the mobile bookmarks. However, I am not able to move the mobile bookmarks to the booksmark bar. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

In chrome desktop, open the mobile bookmarks folder and drag/drop the content in favorite bar like that:

[image: screen]

On Chrome mobile, you can also save bookmark directly on favorite bar.